# unpredictable mysql server behaviour on left join

Tags: mysql

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_userid
(
    uUserId int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE='MEMORY';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_studentid
(
    uClassId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    uUserId int unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(uClassId,uUserId)
) ENGINE='MEMORY';

INSERT INTO tmp_userid
values (18);

INSERT INTO tmp_studentid
values (1,1),
    (1,3),
    (2,15),
    (3,20),
    (3,25),
    (4,35),
    (4,45)
;
```

Now, if I try to execute:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tmp_userid U
LEFT JOIN tmp_studentid S ON U.uUserId = S.uUserId
where  uClassId = 4;

SELECT * FROM tmp_userid U
LEFT JOIN tmp_studentid S ON U.uUserId = S.uUserId AND uClassId = 4;
```

returns different result!

Any one can explain this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: "explain" is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: Disagree - the meaning of the SQL is not the purpose of EXPLAIN it merely shows the execution plan. In this case matang has not understood why the queries behave differently (it's because they are asking different questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you check execution plans with `EXPLAIN` you'll see that first query has `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`. T 
hat's it - mysql does JOINs first, and then filters the result. Since no join output row matches your filter you get empty end result.

The second query does an OUTER JOIN with a condition that is always false, returning NULL for `uClassId` and `uUserId`, but since there's no post-join filtering you get results.